# Accessing $_SESSION breaks video stream in Firefox?

Tags: php, video-streaming

In one of my Zend Framework controllers I want to stream mp4 video through nginx. I have it set up like this:

```
    public function streamAction() {

        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
        if ($this->view->user) { //<--if I skip this check - everything works fine
            $this->getResponse()
                ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=video.mp4')
                ->setHeader('X-Accel-Redirect', '/media/video/video.mp4')
                ->setHeader('Content-type', 'video/mp4')
                ->setHeader('Content-length', '2219550244')
            ;
        }
    }
```

Earlier in a plugin with `preDispatch` I set the user property for the view:

```
...
$view = $layout->getView();
$user = Application_Model_User::get_auth_user(); // here I check the usual Zend_Auth `hasIdentity()`
$view->user = $user;
...
```

but it really doesn't matter where I check user identity, if I check it - the video stream doesn't work in Firefox (it complains on `text/html decoder`) and Opera, but still works in Chrome.

I suppose something is being output with the video if Zend_Auth `hasIdentity` is called. But I really dont understand: I do the check early in the plugin and just assign the result to a view property. If I dont check the property before setting response headers - everything is ok. If I check the view property - then the stream is corrupted, but how?

Also, are there any practices of video streaming like this with Zend security system employed?

**UPDATE**

Well, actually `Zend_Auth` is not what causes the corruption, it's access to `$_SESSION` that does:

```
...
if ($_SESSION) {
    $this->getResponse()
        ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=video.mp4')
        ->setHeader('X-Accel-Redirect', '/media/video/video.mp4')
        ->setHeader('Content-type', 'video/mp4')
        ->setHeader('Content-length', '2219550244')
    ;
}
```

The above also won't give the stream in Firefox and Opera.

**UPDATE 2**

I have simplyfied the code to a 4-lined php file:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['Zend_Auth'])) { // same with $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']
    header('Content-type: video/mp4');
    readfile('/home/user/Videos/video.mp4');
}
```

And again if I remove the check (*or check non-existent key like `$_SESSION['rubbish']`*) - stream is ok in Firefox. The problem is in php sessions, so ZF is out of suspiction.

Comment: If you leave the user check in place but comment out all the setHeader() calls after it, is there any output on the page (such as a PHP error/warning)? Also check for whitespace after the closing ?> in `Application_Model_User`, and things like that.

Comment: @TimFountain thanks for the reply - I did those checks. The output is clean. Moreover I can `echo` anything right before setting headers but don't do the identity check and the stream is still ok!

Comment: What happens if you change your `if ($this->view->user) {` line to `if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {`? That should rule out issues with the user model itself.

Comment: @TimFountain I am experimenting with this right now. `Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()` and `Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()` in the check corrupt the stream. `Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()` - stream is ok

Comment: `if (!Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->isEmpty()) {...}` - stream is corrupted

Comment: Are you passing this video to a Flash player or are you trying to use html5? Your mp4 video is likely h.264 which is not supported in Firefox or Opera in html5. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support and for a possible fix http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/html5-extension-for-wmp-plugin

Comment: @RockyFord thanks for the link but how come the video plays fine if I don't access `$_SESSION`?

Comment: I wish I knew, Firefox has been driving me crazy trying to get it to play mp4/h.264 files. It's even been a problem using 3rd party libraries like Flowplayer and media element.